# ScrollView is failing to scroll its child layout

Tags: android

This is my coding I have added a `Scrollview` and I have dynamic data that I want to scroll but it's not scrolling entirely. I Tried many solution but still its of No use. Please check and if found any error help me. This `scrollview` has a child relative layout. I did the same code before in another activity and that is working fine but here it is not working fine.

Thanks in Advance

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrolllayouts"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linear_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative">
    <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/customerdetails"
                    android:background="@color/backgrey"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/orderlayout"
                        android:background="@drawable/bottomline"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:textSize="20dp"
                      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVOrderIDs"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:text="zzzzzzzzzzz"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/namediv"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/orderlayout"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVCustomerNamelbls"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                      android:text="Customer Name"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVCustomerNamelbls"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVCustomerNames"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVCustomerNames"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVMobilenumbers"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:id="@+id/TVAddTimelbls"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                      android:text="Delivery Time"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVAddTimelbls"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVAddTimes"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVAddTimes"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVtimes"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/amountdivs"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/namediv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
            <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/TVTotAmtlbls"
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                      android:text="Total Amount"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/TVTotAmtss"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVTotAmtlbls"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                      />
            <TextView
                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVTotAmtss"
                      android:id="@+id/TVStatuslbls"
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                      android:text="Order Status"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/TVStatuss"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVStatuslbls"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Delivered"
                      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                      />
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:id="@+id/EDReceivedAmtlbls"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Recieved Amount"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"
                      />
            <TextView
                      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:text=""
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                      android:id="@+id/EDReceivedAmts"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/EDReceivedAmtlbls"
                      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TVTotAmtss"
                      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                      />
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TVStatuslbls"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/EDReceivedAmts"
                      android:id="@+id/EDDeliveredTimelbls"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Delivered Time"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"
                      />
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                      android:id="@+id/DeliveredTimes"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/EDDeliveredTimelbls"
                      android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                      />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_below="@+id/amountdivs"
                        android:id="@+id/titledivs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:id="@+id/TVAddressNamelbls"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:text="Address"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/TVAddressNamelbls"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:id="@+id/TVAddressNames"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/adresdivs"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/titledivs"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/allline"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">
            <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/TVAddresss"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:text=""
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_below="@+id/adresdivs"
                        android:id="@+id/remarksdivs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">
            <TextView
                      android:textSize="15sp"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:id="@+id/EDRemarkslbls"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                      android:text="My Remarks"
                      android:textColor="#faba62"/>
            <TextView
                      android:padding="10dp"
                      android:lines="4"
                      android:minLines="1"
                      android:gravity="top|left"
                      android:maxLines="6"
                      android:id="@+id/EDRemarkss"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="60dp"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/EDRemarkslbls"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                      android:textSize="13dp"
                      android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                      android:background="@drawable/allline"
                      android:textColor="#3c3c3c" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                      android:id="@+id/table"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/remarksdivs"
                      android:background="@color/backgrey"
                      android:padding="10dp"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <HorizontalScrollView
                                      android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                                      android:id="@+id/horizontalViewss"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                      android:scrollbars="horizontal">
                    <TableLayout
                                 android:id="@+id/TBMainss"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TRMainss">
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:textAlignment="center"
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDPrImgs"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:text="Image"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                            <TextView
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDPrNames"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:text="Product"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDCatNames"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:text="Category"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                      />
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                      android:id="@+id/DTVQtys"
                                      android:text="Quantity"
                                      />
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDUOMs"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:text="Unit"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                      />
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDTotAmts"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:text="Amount"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                      />
                            <TextView
                                      android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                      android:id="@+id/TVDBranchNames"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:background="#fce1ac"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                                      android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                      android:text="Branch"
                                      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                      />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**Try to use NestedScrollView**

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

*For androidx supported use below code*

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```